# Passing vector by reference in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose I define the following data structure:

```
struct vector
{
    size_t size;
    int *ptr;
}
```

Although not shown in the above snippet, I add to this struct a decent copy constructor, so that `vector` behaves like `std::vector` when copied. If I want a function to modify a `vector`, I must pass it by reference.

```
void initialize_first_element(vector &v)
{
    if (v.size > 0) v.ptr[0] = 0;
}
```

This would translate in C like

```
void initialize_first_element(struct vector *v)
{
    if (v->size > 0) v->ptr[0] = 0;
}
```

However, I find this code inefficient because of the double indirection `*((*v).ptr) = 0`. Instead, we could write (in C)

```
void initialize_first_element(size_t size, int *ptr)
{
    if (size > 0) ptr[0] = 0;
}
```

which is much more common.

So, is there something wrong? Is there an idiomatic way to achieve in C++ the same level of efficiency there is in C?

Comment: *"So, is there something wrong?"* With what?

Comment: Don't name your own types the same as standard types - in this case `std::vector`. And what exactly is the question?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Far as I can tell, the OP's type is named `::vector`, not `std::vector`.

Comment: A `std::vector` also has a capacity. Not needed when you just want to modify a (sub-)range (which is commonly designated by iterators), but anyway. You might want to take a look at the range-proposal, which will become an idiomatic way to manipulate ranges.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Irrelevant. Naming it "vector" is bound to cause confusion (and name clashes once someone does `using std::vector`) - it's just a bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the same level of efficiency'? Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: You likely don't want to do that in C either, because it exposes implementation details to every single user - which (a) makes every single user responsible for maintaining the data structure's invariants, and (b) makes is next to impossible to change any aspect of the implementation later. In C, you'd have something like `void PutElement(vector* v, int index, int value);`, if you know what's good for you. See also: [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation)

Comment: You can use all the c syntax in c++ if you wish. There is a chance that the compiler optimize the c++ code as well.

Comment: This will be most likely the least inefficient thing in your program.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl The `vector` struct in the question is meant to be a mere example of a simplified `std::vector` (as I don't know the exact members of a `std::vector`. Otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: With a good compiler, the only difference will be the offset computation for `v.ptr`. If you use the second version, you are just moving this computation outside of the function, in the caller context, which does not make your code more efficient.

Comment: @N. Shead In the C++ version, there are two dereferencing

Comment: You are comparing an apple with an orange, and complaining that the apple is not coloured orange.   Your "Instead, we could write (in C)" version relies on `size` and `ptr` being passed by arguments, not members of a struct.   If they are members of a struct, dereferencing is still needed to obtain them.

Comment: @Peter I respectfully disagree with your remark. The point of comparison is to compare *different* things.

Comment: No, the point of comparison is to compare *comparable* things.   Your approaches are not comparable.

Comment: @Peter I asked to compare two different functions which have the same purpose: setting the first element of a vector to zero. The approaches are different because one uses abstraction. I compared these approaches on the effeciency level, because abstraction in C++ has to come with zero cost. So, my question was: is there really a difference regarding efficiency, and if so, if there a "c++ abstract" way to be as efficient as possible. If you do not find this question interesting, please do not comment.

Comment: I am commenting because I consider the premise of your question flawed.   Abstraction does not mean wrapping data in a struct or class.

Comment: @Peter You are misunderstanding me, I never restricted abstraction to wrapping data. However, you should agree that it is much more convenient to deal with `std::vector` rather than array pointers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just use `std::vector`.

Second, until you profile, there is no reason to expect a significant performance hit here.  Following pointers mainly causes problems when there is a cache miss, and an inlined reference is no longer a pointer but an alias.

Third, implement move semantics.  Write

```
vector initialize_first_element(vector v)
{
  if (v.size > 0) v.ptr[0] = 0;
  return v;
}
```

Which passes the object through.

Alternatively, write `vector_view` which is a non-owning view into a subset of a vector that naturally does not copy.

```
void initialize_first_element(vector_view v)
{
  if (v.size > 0) v.ptr[0] = 0;
}
```

and done.

This last construct is known as `span` in modern C++ parliance, and id very useful in many situations.